# qemu request for a disc image

Tags: operating-system, qemu, xv6

I am trying to get qemu up and running with xv6 but I am having some trouble with compiling xv6. what are the types of disc images that qemu accepts. for instance does Qemu accept .ISO files? I tried loading FreeBSD but I am getting the error from QEMU that there is no bootable device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following what's given in this link under the heading "Running xv6 under QEMU" to load xv6 in qemu.
http://zoo.cs.yale.edu/classes/cs422/2010/lec/l2-hw